# Why does this Sparkpost Python SDK Install fail?

Tags: python, sdk, sparkpost

I'm trying to install sparkpost sdk in the read me on git hub. I used the command:

```
pip install sparkpost
```

But I got this error:

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement sparkpost (from versions: 1.0.0.dev1, 1.0.0.dev1)

Comment: What can you tell us about your configuration that would make it easier to diagnose your problem? Can you include more details about the instructions you are following and where things go wrong? It might also be more effective to seek help by searching for that error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SparkPost Python SDK is currently in a pre-release version (that's what the `.dev1` is at the end of the version).

Using pip > version 1.4.X you must explicitly define you want to use a pre-release package using the `--pre` option of pip install [options] command.

Try with this and it should work:

```
pip install --pre sparkpost
```

You may need to run as sudo if you experience permission issues.

I have created a new issue in https://github.com/sparkpost/python-sparkpost repository and I'll add the workaround to the documentation.

Thanks for finding this.

Comment: We added a note to the readme to avoid some confusion, but this is due to the fact that we don't have a non-pre-release version available.

Comment: Note that pip is at version 7.1.2 as of the time of this comment. As of pip 6.0 they fully support PEP 440 which handles installation of pre-release versions without the --pre flag.